# Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC): Does the set form a group with the point at infinity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I get multiple sets of elliptic curves (EC) and need to prove that the set either forms or doesn't form a group with the point at infinity. How do I do that?

## An example

Does the set $E\left(\mathbb{F}_{23}\right)=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{F}_{23} \times \mathbb{F}_{23}: y^{2}=x^{3}+2 x-25\right\}$ form a group with the point at infinity?

Answer (score 3):

I think all you have to do is the following:

$i)$ check that the field has neither characteristic $2$ nor $3$ ($\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{F}_{23})=23$);

$ii)$ check that the curve is non-singular ($4\cdot \color{blue}{2}^3 + 27\cdot (\color{blue}{-25})^2 \not\equiv 0\  \mathrm{ mod}\  23$) .

Comment: Thank you very much. The last part of answer I do get. But I don't get the first part (i). What is it exactly I shall do? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, where $p$ is a prime and $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$ (all finite fields are of this form), then the characteristic is the prime $p$. For example, $\mathbb{F}_{8} = \mathbb{F}_{2^3}$ has characteristic $2$.

Comment: thank you. Last question. Why is 2 and 3 not allowed as characteristic? And is that only for 23 the case or for F_15 the same?